# Is there an alternative flutter camera package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've been using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) flutter camera package for a while. I would like to use the package to simply take a picture. Recently, I've been unable to take any pictures because the plugin crashes. I found [this bug report](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92973#issuecomment-1024621306) where others complained about the same issue. Given that it is a basic feature of the camera I was waiting with the hope that it would be resolved quickly. But it has not, are there any alternative camera packages that can take a picture? I have done some searching but most camera packages I come across ultimately have a dependency on this camera plugin with the open bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look the image picker plugin you can find it under pub.dev > search: image picker > click on the first one.

Comment: Thanks, I was just coming back to post about this. I did end up using the `image_picker` plugin. It works since it does not depend on the `camera` plugin but it offers no customization to the camera interface it provides. But it's better than nothing. Thanks again.